# How to set content-type and POST for backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can I set `content-type` and `POST` in backbone.js?

```
this.save(data, {
    success: function (user) {
        callback(user.get('LoginStatus'))
    },

    error: function (user, result, xhr) {

    }
});
```

I am getting bad-request when I try to make a REST service call, it works in fiddler. Do we need to set the type and Content-type?

Here is the error i get

```
[ERROR][TiHttpClient(  636)] (TiHttpClient-1) [13340,13340] HTTP Error (org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException): Bad Request
[ERROR][TiHttpClient(  636)] org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
[ERROR][TiHttpClient(  636)]    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:240)
[ERROR][TiHttpClient(  636)]    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:199)
[ERROR][TiHttpClient(  636)]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
[ERROR][TiHttpClient(  636)]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:637)
[ERROR][TiHttpClient(  636)]    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1217)
[ERROR][TiHttpClient(  636)]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
[ERROR][TiAPI   (  636)]  [REST API] ERROR: " *** FaultException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
[ERROR][TiAPI   (  636)]  [REST API] apiCall ERROR: " *** FaultException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Comment: what's the reason for the bad-request? status code, body output?

Comment: @ChuckE: exception updated.

Comment: which url sens the REST request? can you confirm that you are dressing an existing resource?

Answer (score 8):

As the backbone `fetch` and `save` methods wrap the `jQuery.ajax()` function you can set the Content-Type and Request Method in Backbone by passing in the a `jQuery.ajax()` `settings` object directly to either the `fetch` or `save` function

For example using the `fetch` function:

```
myModel.fetch({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Its the same using the `save` function:

```
myModel.save({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Also I notice you are providing a data property in your `save` function. if you want to pass JSON as POSTed data to a URL, you'll need the following syntax in your `save` function:

```
myModel.save({
    data: JSON.stringify(myObject),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand the error posted but if all you want to do is set the content-type or alter some other default settings in the call, then its quite possible.

If you take a look at the save function for the Model prototype in Backbone, it actually is using  this.sync or the default 'Backbone.sync' method to make the call. Checking the Backbone.sync function, you can see that it is actually using the jquery's 'ajax' method to make the call. Note line 
return $.ajax(_.extend(params, options));
hence you should be able to pass anything as options to it that the jquery's ajax method would take. In the same sync method you can also see you how it is setting the standard default content type, params.contentType = 'application/json';

You could also write your own sync method for the Model and make your own ajax call changing the default parameters. If your Model has its own sync method, it would then be called instead of the default Backbone.sync method.